# C++: Array of differents types of objects (access to the methods of the child class)

Tags: c++, oop, c++17

I have created an array of `Position` which is a parent class of several classes : `Player`, `Item`, `Mob`, and `Map`.

I want to create an array of several types of objects in my `Position` array (dynamically created object) and then want to use the methods of my objects which are unique.

I can't use the virtual type because I would have to write the methods of all my classes and it would be incoherent.

So I ask you to try to solve this problem.

Map.h :

```
...
static constexpr int mapColonne{14};
static constexpr int mapLigne{6};
Position *positionObject[mapLigne][mapColonne];
...
```

Map.cpp :

```
...
positionObject[i][j] = new Player("Player1");
positionObject[i][j]->infoPlayer();
...
```

> Error: class "Position" has no member "infoPlayer

Comment: "I can't use the virtual type because I would have to write the methods of all my classes" Not really. You only have to implement virtual methods in subclasses of they need to override the base class implementation.

Comment: Have you thought of using different arrays for each object type? And having each object know its position?

Comment: Also, `Position` should be called something like `PositionObject`. That would make inheritance visible. On the other hand, it should tell you that the design is not good because you should only have `Object`s (holding a position), not `PositionObject`s.

Comment: A good OO design need a good naming for the methods. Just naming infoPalyer to infoPosition will let you to define it as virtual in the base class and then overide it on derived class like Player... Then everything will be straigthforward

Comment: The problem is that I have 10 classes that use a position each that will be assigned to the position they will have on a map (2D array) and each object has its own method, so I can't structure it differently.
The class Position allows me to make an array to initialize dynamically each object and then to assign to each object a different position.

Comment: For me it is unclear what the question is about! Have a position base class and derive from it and have virtual methods to reflect the specific differences for the concrete derived objects. What is the problem? If you do not update your question, nobody can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have following options, depending on what do you want to happen if the element doesn't contain the type you think it does:

- `static_cast<Player *>(positionObject[i][j])->infoPlayer();` - undefined behavior on type mismatch.
- `dynamic_cast<Player *>(positionObject[i][j])->infoPlayer();` - cast returns null on type mismatch, which you can check for. If you don't check for null, calling a method on a null pointer might crash.
- `dynamic_cast<Player &>(*positionObject[i][j]).infoPlayer();` - exception on type mismatch.

I would use:

- (3) if I think I know the right type.
- (1) if I'm absolutely certain I know the type.
- (2) if I want to check the type first, and do something else if it doesn't match.

---

`dynamic_cast` is often a sign of bad design. I see no reason to use it here. All your classes should have common methods (declared in base class), such as `draw()`, `update()`, etc, which you would call for every object on the board.